# How To Access Many to Many Attribute in Django

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I am very new to web development and I have created a sample project using Django.  So far I have a Django powered page that displays the contents of one of my database's model objects which is called Publications.  The code I have in my view template is:

```
<html><head><title>Publications</title></head>
<body>
<h1>Publications</h1>
<ul>
{% for publication in publication_list %}
<li>{{ publication.title }} </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
</body></html>
```

This works fine, but now I would like to access and display a many to many attribute on Publications called Tags.  I have tried adding another for tag as follows:

```
<html><head><title>Publications</title></head>
<body>
<h1>Publications</h1>
<ul>
{% for publication in publication_list %}
<li>{{ publication.title }} </li>
{% for tag in publication_list.tags %}
<li>{{ tag.title }} </li>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
</body></html>
```

I realize this is quite wrong, but I don't see how to access the Tags model. For reference, my function for displaying the publications in the view is:

```
def display_publications(request):
    publication_list = Publication.objects.order_by('title')[:10]
    return render(request, 'publications.html', {'publication_list': publication_list})
```

And my Publications and Tag Models are:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Publication(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing only accesses the ManyRelatedManager.  You need to specify a query against that manager.  In python, it would be:

```
publication.tags.all()
```

In a django template it would be:

```
{% for tag in publication.tags.all %}
   {{ tag }}
{% endfor %}
```

This should be covered in the official documention on many-to-many relationships.

**Edit:** Here's a good example of how many-to-many relationships work: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Answer (score 0):

Because you seem to be having some trouble with this, given your comments on the other question, here are the changes to the template. You do not need to modify the view at all from what you have given above.

```
{% for publication in publication_list %}
  <li>{{ publication.title }}
  <ul>
  {% for tag in publication.tags.all %}
    <li>{{ tag.title }} </li>
  {% endfor %}
  </li>
  </ul>
{% endfor %}
```